# How to run eclipse on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I've copied my eclipse from my office laptop to home laptop , both of which are running on Ubuntu 13.10. Well the problem is when I start the eclipse on my home laptop  it gives me an error :

```
There is no application installed for “executable” files.
Do you want to search for an application to open this file
```

I don't get it ,is it an executable file that i'm starting and i need tools like WINE for this or what type of file is it ,to be clear i want to know what kind of file ubuntu has in contrast to windows < .exe > executable files

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/254220/there-is-no-application-installed-for-executable-files

Answer (score 1):

Try to right+click on eclipse icon -> properties .. go to permission tab. 
Then make sure that the check box "Allow executing file as program" is checked.